# Showing a div if any one of 4 inputs match value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 questions, each question has a yes and no answer in the form of a text link. Each text link sends a value to a dedicated hidden field for the answer to that question. All of that is working perfect as it is...

However, when any one of these hidden values equals "yes" I want to show a div, lets just say this div has the content "You answered yes to one of the questions".

This is how I am currently getting the yes/no value to the field: http://jsfiddle.net/w3yuv4Lw/

I had the idea of having something like:

```
if ($("#question1a,#question1b,#question1c").filter(function()
    { return $(this).val(); }).length > 1)
    }
```

As I've set the default for the values as x, but there's a no value too, so I really need it to match "yes" and then display the div.

I have to be honest though, I don't really have any idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that answer had a problem too. It only checked the last value and not the already set value. So if one box has `yes` and latest value is `no` it will hide the div again. Here's the answer after solving that problem too. Its working fine for every condition.

```
<div id="dv" style="display:none;"> Congrats! Correct answer. </div>

$('a[class*="question"]').on('click', function () {
$("#dv").css("display", "none");
var answer = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1];
$('#' + $(this).prop('class')).val(answer);
check();
});
function check() {
  var ans1 = $("#questionOne").val();
  var ans2 = $("#questionTwo").val();
    if(ans1=='yes'||ans2=='yes')
    {
        $("#dv").css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

**[UpdatedDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3yuv4Lw/10/)**

Comment: Unfortunately this shows the div whether you click yes or no.

EDIT: Well, doesn't show if you click either, but it doesn't disappear when you click "no".

Comment: Actually, Syed's answer works -- he just missed the need to re-hide the #dv div after any click, just in case the click was a No. See http://jsfiddle.net/w3yuv4Lw/7/  (Syed, feel free to switch your jsFiddle reference to this one)

Comment: @gibberish: Thank you for the edit. I forgot that but I updated the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Trying to understand it now and the differences from the original code. If I have more answers that shouldn't affect this div, but have yes values, can I separate it by splitting the code and saying it only applies to certain input fields?

Comment: @BN83 Yes, I already did that. The new code now checks each field separately. And please mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: Also feel free to ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I will if I can't get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append()` to add the HTML to your page:

```
if(answer == "yes" && $("#yes").length==0){
   var html = '<div id="yes">You answered yes to one of the questions!</div>';
   $(this).append(html);
}
```

Change the `this` in `$(this).append(html);` to wherever you want to place the HTML.  For example you could create an empty `<div>` on your page like `<div id="stuff"></div>` and then `$("#stuff").append(html);` will place the HTML inside that div.

If you want to prevent the appended `<div id="yes">` from being appended multiple times then add a condition to your if statement, and use the `length()` function, which checks the number of times an element appears on a page.

To remove the text when user clicks on "no" do this:

```
if(answer == "no"){
    $("#yes").remove();
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w3yuv4Lw/9/)**

Comment: Unfortunately if you click yes, then no, then yes again, it creates another line of "hello". I just want it to show a predefined, hidden div.

Comment: Understood, that was not specified in the original question, but check out option 2

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this shows the div if you click yes, then no. Can it remove the div if the wrong option is selected again?

Comment: Sure I could do that, but you didn't specify all of these things in your original question.  You should really make an effort to be more specific when writing your question, and to learn this stuff and not just have people do it for you.  You can use the above answer and add a [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: Apologies, but I thought I described that when I said "show a div" rather than "create a div". And I am trying to learn, but the easiest way to learn is to get an answer and understand it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Again, apologies. I just assumed it was logical to hide a div when the answer selected is no longer yes... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the "remove" function...I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code:

```css
#div_to_show {display:none;}
input[type=hidden][value="yes"] ~ #div_to_show {display:block;}
```

This will work as long as the `<input>` and the `<div>` have **THE SAME PARENT**.